# material Design with Angular Dart and Polymer dart. Compilation issues

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, angular-dart, material-design, paper-elements

I am at my whits end here. I've been trying over the last 48 hours to get these technologies to work.I've read everywhere that they should be able to work but it's just one problem after the other. I've tried various combinations of my pubspeck.yaml file but the results I get are either the code simply wont build, or it just doesn't work >.>

I'll appreciate any help I can get!

my pubspeck.yaml:

```yaml
name: blah
dependencies:
angular: 0.12.0
  angular_node_bind: any
  shadow_dom: any
  browser: any
  polymer: ">=0.11.0 <0.12.0"
  core_elements: ">=0.0.6 <0.1.0"
  paper_elements: any
transformers:
- angular
- polymer:
    entry_points:
        - web/index.html
dependency_overrides:
  polymer: ">= 0.11.1-dev < 0.12.0"
  browser: any
  web_components: 0.4.0
  analyzer: ">=0.15.6 <0.16.0"
  html5lib: ">=0.11.0 <0.12.0"
```

My dart file:

```dart
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:angular/application_factory.dart';
import 'package:angular_node_bind/angular_node_bind.dart';

// HACK until we fix code gen size. This doesn't really fix it,
// just makes it better.
@MirrorsUsed(override: '*')
import 'dart:mirrors';

void main() {
  initPolymer().run(() {
    applicationFactory().addModule(new AppModule()).addMdoule(new NodeBindModule()).run();
  });
}
```

and finally my html:

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title>GTHR</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

        <link href="css/screen.css" media="screen, projection" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js"></script>

        <!-- <script src="packages/web_components/platform.js"></script>
             not necessary anymore with Polymer >= 0.14.0 -->
        <script src="packages/web_components/dart_support.js"></script>

        <link rel="import" href="packages/paper_elements/paper_tabs.html">
        <link rel="import" href="packages/paper_elements/paper_tab.html">
        <link rel="import" href="packages/core_elements/core_header_panel.html">
        <link rel="import" href="packages/core_elements/core_toolbar.html">
        <script type="application/dart" src="Application.dart"></script>
        <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body fullbleed layout vertical>
        <!--[if lt IE 7]>
            <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->

        <core-header-panel mode="waterfall">
            <div class="core-header">
                My App
            </div>
            <div>
                <core-toolbar>
                    <paper-tabs selected="0" role="tablist">
                        <paper-tab>World</paper-tab>
                        <paper-tab>Followers</paper-tab>
                        <paper-tab>Mine</paper-tab>
                    </paper-tabs>
                </core-toolbar>
            </div>
        </core-header-panel>

        <div class="main-container">
            <div class="main wrapper clearfix">
            </div> <!-- #main -->
        </div> <!-- #main-container -->

        <div class="footer-container">
            <footer class="wrapper">
                <h3>footer</h3>
            </footer>
        </div>

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="packages/shadow_dom/shadow_dom.debug.js"></script>

        <script src="js/flowtype.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>

        <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID. -->
        <script>
            (function(b,o,i,l,e,r){b.GoogleAnalyticsObject=l;b[l]||(b[l]=
            function(){(b[l].q=b[l].q||[]).push(arguments)});b[l].l=+new Date;
            e=o.createElement(i);r=o.getElementsByTagName(i)[0];
            e.src='http://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js';
            r.parentNode.insertBefore(e,r)}(window,document,'script','ga'));
            ga('create','UA-XXXXX-X');ga('send','pageview');
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

with my the following as is, Dart2js gives me the following output:

With the pubspeck.yaml I get the following output:

```dart
Loading source assets... 
Loading smoke/src/default_transformer transformers... 
Loading di transformers... (1.7s)
Loading observe transformers... 
Loading angular transformers... 
Loading polymer/src/build/mirrors_remover transformers... 
Loading polymer transformers... 
Loading polymer transformers... 
Loading polymer transformers... (1.0s)
Building gthr-web... (14.1s)
[Info from Dart2JS]:
Compiling gthr-web|web/Application_static_expressions.dart...
[Error from Dart2JS]:
web/Application_static_expressions.dart:1:13:
Expected ';', but got '-'.
library gthr-web.web.Application.generated_expressions;
            ^
[Info from Dart2JS]:
Took 0:00:00.519007 to compile gthr-web|web/Application_static_expressions.dart.
[Info from Dart2JS]:
Compiling gthr-web|web/Application.dart...
[Error from Dart2JS on gthr-web|web/Application.dart]:
web/Application_static_expressions.dart:1:13:
Expected ';', but got '-'.
library gthr-web.web.Application.generated_expressions;
            ^
[Info from Dart2JS]:
Took 0:00:00.591015 to compile gthr-web|web/Application.dart.
[Info from Dart2JS]:
Compiling gthr-web|web/Application_static_injector.dart...
[Error from Dart2JS]:
web/Application_static_injector.dart:1:13:
Expected ';', but got '-'.
library gthr-web.web.Application.generated_static_injector;
            ^
[Info from Dart2JS]:
Took 0:00:00.501912 to compile gthr-web|web/Application_static_injector.dart.
[Info from Dart2JS]:
Compiling gthr-web|web/Application_static_metadata.dart...
[Error from Dart2JS]:
web/Application_static_metadata.dart:1:13:
Expected ';', but got '-'.
library gthr-web.web.Application.generated_metadata;
            ^
[Info from Dart2JS]:
Took 0:00:00.151240 to compile gthr-web|web/Application_static_metadata.dart.
[Info from Dart2JS]:
Compiling gthr-web|web/index.html_bootstrap.dart...
[Error from Dart2JS on gthr-web|web/index.html_bootstrap.dart]:
web/Application_static_expressions.dart:1:13:
Expected ';', but got '-'.
library gthr-web.web.Application.generated_expressions;
            ^
[Info from Dart2JS]:
Took 0:00:00.916099 to compile gthr-web|web/index.html_bootstrap.dart.
Build failed.
```

Comment: What's your problem exactly? "Won't build" and "doesn't work" are not helpful at all.

Comment: Depending on what versions of Angular and Polymer I mismatch, either nothing happens to the DOM or, I get a compilation error from dart2js when it tries to build my dart file.

Comment: I created a bug report/feature request to improve the developer experience https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=20025

Comment: Do you have the angular dependency in pubspec.yaml really in the first column or is this just a formatting error in your question?

Comment: I created a project with the code you provided. 
`AppModule` in `main()` is not recognized (yellow wavy underline). Can you confirm this with your environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just started to look at your code (maybe I find more hints/suggestions/problems)

You should try to change

```
polymer: ">=0.11.1-dev <0.12.0"
```

to

```
polymer: ">=0.12.0-dev <0.12.0"
```

This pre-release version of the Polymer package contains some paper-elements related bug-fixes.

It seems you are using a `-` (dash) in a library identifier where this character is invalid. You also shouldn't use a dash in Dart file names and all-lowercase characters.

**EDIT**
The package `shadow_dom` is deprecated see http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shadow_dom for more information

**EDIT**

```
applicationFactory().addModule(new AppModule()).addMdoule(new NodeBindModule()).run();
```

the second `addModule` is misspelled (`addMdoule`)

Comment: I'm still getting the same output from pub build.

Comment: I updated my answer. The error message you added shows that you used a dash in a library name which is not allowed.

Comment: hmm, I have no idea where that "-" is coming from. All if have written is posted here. Could it be a bug in something loaded with the pubspec?

Comment: Where does `gthr-web` coming from? Is this your package name? You shouldn't use a dash here either.

Comment: Thanks man, turns out the - in my package name was the issue. Now the code will build but I'm running into other issues. I'll post a new question if i get stuck again. Chao!

Comment: I added another hint to my answer.

Comment: The suggested version no longer exists. Use polymer: ">=0.12.0 <0.13.0"

Answer (score 1):

Also keep in mind that you can override automatically resolved dependent packages versions in `dependency_overrides`. This is what currently works for me:

```yaml
dependencies:
  angular: ">=0.12.0 <0.13.0"
  polymer: ">=0.12.0-dev <0.13.0"
  #core_elements: any
  paper_elements: any
dependency_overrides:
  analyzer: "0.15.6"
  html5lib: "0.11.0"
  web_components: "0.4.0"
dev_dependencies:
  mock: any
  unittest: any
transformers:
- angular
- polymer:
    entry_points: web/main.html
```

source: [angular-dart@groups.google.com : AngularDart and PaperElements](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular-dart/HbZ0HCTUpdk/LnI4UOQu9M0J)